# catching up to a party

Tags: word-choice

I know the expression "to catch a bus/plane/train". Would you say "to catch a party" or "to catch up to a party"? I want to convey that I am rushing to a party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rushing (hurrying) to the party. You **catch** (succeed in boarding, meeting, seeing, etc) something or someone that you will **miss** if you are even slightly late. You will probably miss a bus, plane, or train that is scheduled to leave at a certain time, if you are even one minute late. You will not miss a party if you arrive a short time after it starts, thus 'catch' is not suitable.

> Catch (verb, transitive)
>
> to be in time to travel on or do something:
>
> *She was worried that she'd arrive too late to catch the last bus home.*
>
> *catch the post You'll have to run if you want to catch the post (= send something before the post has been collected).*

[Catch (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch)

Comment: When we talk about possibly [***catching a movie***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22catch+a+movie%22), there's rarely any implication of needing to be punctual to avoid missing it. That usage normally just means we'll ***make time*** (often, in a busy schedule) to engage in some (additional, unplanned) activity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am fond of _catching forty winks_, and I believe our American cousins _catch some zees_, and —as you say— _catch movies_ (arrange/manage to see films). I would find it straining the meaning to say that I am running/driving fast (etc) to _catch a party_.

Comment: You might also say "I caught [some presenter / DJ / whatever] on the radio this morning" with no implication of hurrying or being on time. That's just the audio version of visual "I caught sight of him at the party last night".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think we're skipping about among the registers here - 'catch a train' is suitable for all levels of formality, but I don't know about a movie, radio presenter, news story etc. If you catch my meaning.